# How is いらっしゃる used with nouns?

Tags: honorifics

お客様は継続ご希望でいらっしゃいますか？　それとも解約ご希望でしょうか？

I understand the meaning of the above sentence and that いらっしゃる is the honorific form of be, come, and go, but I don't understand how//why it's being used with ご希望. Is で being used before it because 希望 is a noun?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

でいらっしゃる is merely the honorific form of です. いらっしゃる itself is not the honorific for 'to be', but for いる, 来る and 行く.

Comment: I see. So then is でいらっしゃる the honorific form of でございます?

Comment: To be more accurate, でいらっしゃる is a 'subject-exalting' honorific; this means the subject of でいらっしゃる is being exalted, so it is the subject-exalting honorific form of です. The terminology is confusing; ござる and いらっしゃる will both be called 'honorifics', but ござる, as far as I can see, is more of an 'exalted' form. It doesn't elevate the subject in any way, it is just a more elegant version of ある, and so でございます is more elegant than であります or です. You will see であります sometimes called the 'plain polite' form of です, but です itself is polite (possibly a contraction of であります).

Comment: For a thorough discussion of keigo, not too technical I think, you might consult [this](https://intapi.sciendo.com/pdf/10.2478/topling-2015-0001)

Comment: Perfect. Cheers for that